# Contradiction between Ex 4:10 & Acts 7:22?

Tags: contradiction, exodus, acts, moses

Is there a contradiction between Ex 4:10 & Acts 7:22?

> Ex 4:10 - “Please, Lord,” Moses replied, “**I have never been
> eloquent, neither in the past nor since** You have spoken to Your
> servant, for I am slow of speech and tongue.”

> Acts 7:22 - So Moses was educated in all the wisdom of the Egyptians
> and was **powerful in speech** and action.

In Ex 4:10 Moses claims to have never been a good speaker, but in Acts 7:22, Moses is said to be powerful in speech.

Answer (score 2):

Acts 7:22 is when Moses was still in Egypt and had the authority from being in Pharaoh's court. Exodus 4:10 is when Moses had been away from Egypt for 40 years and no longer had the authority of Pharaoh's court. (See the question https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/118787/do-we-ignore-the-language-differences-interpreting-moses-being-not-a-man-of-word).  Moses does seem to exaggerate his condition in Exodus 4:10.

> But Moses said to the LORD, “Please, O Lord, I have never been a man of words, either in times past or now that You have spoken to Your servant; I am slow of speech and slow of tongue.” (Exodus 4:10, JPS)

While Acts 7:22 may speak of Moses' authority as part of Pharaoh's court rather than his ability to articulate.

> And Moses was instructed in all the wisdom of the Egyptians, and he was mighty in his words and deeds.
> (Acts 7:22, ESV)

Moses's response in Exodus 4:10 was when God asked him to speak to Pharaoh (Exodus 3:18).  It is true that Moses probably was not outspoken within Pharaoh's court, while his words would have held authority to Pharaoh's subjects.

Another possible aspect of Acts 7:22 is it may refer to Moses's confrontation with Pharaoh over the ten plagues in Egypt.  The would be when his words and deeds were the most powerful.  However, this would mean the narrative wasn't in chronological order.

Comment: It had been 40 years since Moses was in Egypt...perhaps that is why?

Comment: Good answer . +1.